# Pandas boxplot: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I have a data frame, `df`, of size `2x2`. When I call `df.boxplot()` I get a `IndexError: list index out of range` error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code.py", line 155, in <module>
    main()
  File "my_code.py", line 135, in main
    df.boxplot()
  File "/server/software/rhel7/python27_pandas-0.19.2-mkl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5749, in boxplot
    return_type=return_type, **kwds)
  File "/server/software/rhel7/python27_pandas-0.19.2-mkl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2797, in boxplot
    result = plot_group(columns, data.values.T, ax)
  File "/server/software/rhel7/python27_pandas-0.19.2-mkl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2751, in plot_group
    bp = ax.boxplot(values, **kwds)
  File "/server/software/rhel7/python27_matplotlib-1.5.1-mkl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/server/software/rhel7/python27_matplotlib-1.5.1-mkl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3212, in boxplot
    labels=labels)
  File "/server/software/rhel7/python27_matplotlib-1.5.1-mkl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1980, in boxplot_stats
    X = _reshape_2D(X)
  File "/server/software/rhel7/python27_matplotlib-1.5.1-mkl/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 2245, in _reshape_2D
    if not hasattr(X[0], '__len__'):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Interestingly, if I do `df.iloc[1,:] = [200, 210]`, the error disappears. However, running `df.iloc[1,0] = 200; df.iloc[1,1] = 210` doesn't fix the error. What could the issue be?

---

`print(df)`:

```
      C_5  C_10
Date
0     100  150
1     200  210
```

`print(df)` looks the same after `df.iloc[1,:] = [200, 210]` or after `df.iloc[1,0] = 200; df.iloc[1,1] = 210` (which is expected).

Comment: Can you add the contents of your DataFrame please?

Comment: @Mitch What's the best way to copy the content in the question? (If I do `df = pd.DataFrame({...})`  the issue goes away, so I couldn't provide a MWE)

Comment: ...then what is `df` when you are calling `boxplot` on it? That's what I want to see.

Comment: @Mitch Sounds good, added in the question. Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `df.to_dict()`  and `df.info()`?

Comment: I found the issue, writing the answer in the next few minutes. dtype issues.

Comment: Presumably they were strings.

Comment: @Mitch `object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `print('df.dtypes: \n{0}'.format(df.dtypes))`, the issue is that the `dtypes` was `object`

```
df.dtypes: 
C_5     float64
C_10    object
```

whereas it should be:

```
df.dtypes: 
C_5     float64
C_10    float64
```

otherwise you'll get the very explicit error message `IndexError: list index out of range`.